# Extjs 3.4 ComboBox: how to preselect a record when the combobox is first loaded?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using Extjs 3.4. I need to set up a type ahead combobox like this:
The combobox is using a JsonStore, when the combobox is first loaded onto the page, I need to preselect a value. Later on, the user can change the value to other record.

```
combobox.store.on("load",function(){
    combobox.setValue(value);
});
```

But the value will be set every time the combobox is loaded. I only need to set up the value when it is first loaded.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag in the parent scope (outside of the anon function):

```
var selectDefault = true;
combobox.store.on("load",function(){
    if (selectDefault) {
        combobox.setValue(value);
        selectDefault = false;
    }
});
```